# What does QCD look like in higher dimensions?

Tags: particle-physics, renormalization, quantum-chromodynamics, spacetime-dimensions

It was pointed out as a comment on [my question on atomic physics in higher dimensions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/491980/plum-pudding-atomic-physics-in-higher-dimensions) that that question implicitly rests on an assumption that QCD, and thus the structure of atomic nuclei, is pretty much unchanged in higher dimensions. That seems a reasonable assumption to me, based on my admittedly extremely sketchy knowledge of QCD (which might reasonably be summarized as "gluon-mediated forces between quarks act like springs, so dimensionality doesn't matter"), but it is indeed an assumption. While there is plenty of internet-accessible discussion on the effects on electromagnetism when moving into higher dimensions, cursory searching on my part was only able to turn up [two](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.97.025009) [papers](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0202171) on higher-dimension QCD, neither of which address the structure of nucleons or nuclei.

So, what does happen to QCD in higher dimensions? Do we still get neutrons and protons in 4+1, 5+1, or higher-dimensional spacetimes, or does stuff get Weird?

Comment: To be fair, we don't even know if $3+1$ QCD really does predict protons and neutrons. It is an educated guess, backed up by indirect data, but we have no ab-initio proof.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Is it therefore reasonable to assume that nuclear structure in higher dimensions *can* be analogous to that of our universe, in the absence of a proof that it should be otherwise?

Comment: Reasonable? who's to say. On the one hand, a Coulomb-like effective description suggests that no bound states exist in $d>4$ (cf. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/255961/84967). On the other hand, the generalized Coleman-Mermin-Wagner theorem suggests that the center can be broken in $d\ge4$, so one may expect confinement. But I don't think we have tools powerful enough to settle the question in $d=4$, let alone in $d>4$. Heck, I don't even know what the beta function looks like in $d>4$ (but this is probably easy to find online if one wants to).

Comment: Related: [Would Color Confinement apply in higher dimensions?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/481727). Although that other question is related, the only currently-posted answer (mine) is about lattice QCD, rather than QCD in continuous spacetime. The answer posted here by  @HansMoleman addresses the situation in continuous spacetime, which is presumably what the question is really about.

Answer (score 5):

Yang-Mills theory is IR free in $D \geq 5$ dimensions. So at low energies any such theory is non-interacting: in particular there are no bound states of quarks. Moreover, it's not clear how to "construct" $D \geq 5$ nonabelian gauge theory at short distances - you can't just take the continuum limit. This just means that any such theory can only arise as a low-energy approximation of a UV theory that has more degrees of freedom. If anything, QCD in $D=4$ is qualitatively pretty close to the situation in $D=3$, and to a lesser extent to QCD in $D=2$.